# Can we use SAS URL in Azure Functions to listen to Azure Blob Storage Events?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Can we use SAS URL in Azure Functions to listen to Azure Blob Storage Events?

Storage Account is managed by different team and only the container in the storage account I have access to and  I want to build a solution based on the storage events. I tried with SAS URL, it didn't work. I couldn't find any document that says its possible or not possible.

Comment: You say you have access, so why not use a blob trigger? i.e. use the standard approach. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: Isn't Blob Trigger require connection string? Can we use SAS URL for it? I can access the container only using SAS URL

Comment: Can those who administer the storage account see your function?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. The `connection` property used by the BlobTrigger function in the Azure Functions helps in establishing the connection to the Azure Blob Storage. This property takes either a `connectionString` name or `identity based connection` from the appSettings. The same has been explained in [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#connections) article. There is no option to specify the SAS here. Hope this answers.